# Using Regex in webscraper.io

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I'm using the chrome extension "webscraper.io" to scrape some information using regex

I used [0-9]+ to extract numbers from line

The problem is that the code return the whole line not the matching only

the code:

```
cityId&[0-9]+
```

the result : `cityId&31`

I need only the matching `31`

Comment: Try `cityId&([0-9]+)` and see if you can get group 1 of the match

Comment: @Bohemian♦  Still the same result

Comment: I’m not familiar with webscraper, but you are able to specify group 1 to be returned, and you have used the regex in my previous comment (note that it’s not the same as the regex in your question), then either you will get `31` or webscraper is buggy

Comment: Did it by using positive lookbehind `?<=`

Answer (score 1):

using positive lookbehind `?<=` 
the final code:

```
(?<=cityId&)[0-9]+
```

Comment: javascript regex does not do lookbehinds

Comment: I know, but I tested it on webscraper.io and it works